# How to block access to a particular memory location is accessed

Tags: linux, memory-management, kernel, process-management

I am working on a problem statement in which I have to enforce processes to not share a particular variable in the process over the network.
I am willing to learn and develop in kernel mode as well. 
I will give an example. 
There is a process P which is generating data. This data is stored in the process in a variable v.
Then there is my module M. Now I want M (Which can be a kernel module) to not let P share this data over network. 
How should I approach this problem?

Comment: It is problem for **research**: it has no best approach, requires additional specifications (e.g., what *exactly* `P shares this data over network` *means*?) and even with that specifications the answer would be long. Not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay. how should i approach? I don't mind researching this and giving it time. What should be my starting point and direction? I am pretty comfortable in linux user space and have explored very trivially, kernel programming.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with that.